# YADCF Apply AND Filterring to Multiple Selections From a JSON Array

Tags: json, sharepoint-2010, datatables, yadcf

I want to apply AND filtering to multiple selections from a JSON array.

```
'Classification' Data:
Row 0: [Cats, Dogs]
Row 1: [Cats]
Row 2: [Birds, Cats, Dogs]

Filter selection: Cats and Dogs

Result: Display Rows 0 and 2
```

But (1) this results in OR filtering, and (2) the filter selection choices are the entire contents of each row.  So the rows in the picker look like:

```
Cats, Dogs
Cats
Birds, Cats, Dogs
```

When the choices should look like:

```
Birds
Cats
Dogs
```

Here is the code:

```
var call = $.ajax({
                    url: "https://.../_vti_bin/listdata.svc/DocLib?$expand=Classification",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    headers: {Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"}
                });

    call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){

            myData = data.d.results;
            var dtTable = $('#example').DataTable({
            data: myData,
            columns:[
                {data: "Classification.results[, ].Value"}
                ],
            stateSave: true
            });

            yadcf.init(dtTable, [
                    {column_number:0,
                    filter_type: "multi_select"                     
                    }]);
            });
```

Note - [I read this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/24216/datatables-filtering-with-yadcf-multiselect-and-tags) and wanted to add that data choices in the rows is always in the same order.  So there isn't an issue of one row being:

```
[Dogs, Birds, Cats]
```

Also, when I try to use

```
text_data_delimiter:","
```

I get the error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Value' of undefined or null reference 
jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js, line 412 character 4
```

Comment: you will find your answer in the following sample  http://codepen.io/Dravenrip/pen/OPJdKz , you must use the `filter_type: 'multi_select_custom_func'` learn that sample and you should be fine, if not, let me know

Comment: Hi Daniel,  That's a great demo - I was able to modify and get AND filtering to work.  Two questions (1) the table doesn't reset when the choices are cleared, returning `exGetColumnFilterVal error: no such filter_type: multi_select_custom_func` and (2) Say you have many filter values - is there a smarter way filter besides hand jamming `value', `label`, `cases` and `found`  items?

Comment: 1) is a bug, you can try fixing it yourself and send a pull request (maybe adding another case for `multi_select_custom_func ` just above the `custom_func ` will be enough. 2) please elaborate more about it, because I did not understand you

Comment: Having trouble fixing - any other ideas?  To line 3424 of yadcf.js I added:   `case multi_select_custom_func':
   retVal = $('#yadcf-filter-' + table_selector_jq_friendly + '-' + column_number).val();
   console.log("retVal: "+retVal);
   if (retVal === null) {
   retVal = '';
   }
   break;`

Comment: Open an issue, and provide a test case (jsbin / etc) to test it on...

Comment: Done.  [Here is a link](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/266).  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Daniel!

[Working JS Fiddle answer.](http://jsfiddle.net/user1508773/wkwhmcb1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var dtTable= $('#example').DataTable({}); 

function myCustomFilterFunction(filterVal, columnVal) {
    if (filterVal === null) {return true;}
    if (filterVal){
        var found;
        var myElement;
        var foundTout = 0;
        var nbElemSelected = filterVal.length;

         for (i=0; i<nbElemSelected; i++)
         {
          myElement = filterVal[i];
          switch (myElement) {
            case 'Starch':found = columnVal.search(/Starch/g);
            break;
            case 'Fruit':found = columnVal.search(/Fruit/g);
            break;
            default:found = 1;
            break;
            } 
          if (found !== -1) {foundTout++;}
      }  
      if (foundTout == filterVal.length) {return true;}
      else {return false;}
    } 
} 

yadcf.init(dtTable, [
    {column_number:1,
    select_type: "select2",
    filter_type: 'multi_select_custom_func',
    custom_func: myCustomFilterFunction,
    filter_reset_button_text:"Clear",
    filter_default_label:"select",
    data: [
        {value: 'Starch', label: 'Starch'}, 
        {value: 'Fruit', label: 'Fruit'}
        ]
   }]);
});
```